# What is the config to run spark on multiple cores in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, parallel-processing

When I install spark locally on my server, I use the following code in pyspark to specify the number of cores to use for a spark application. But when I use a Java project to install through maven dependencies and run spark-java program, the same config doesn't parallelize on multiple cores.

I am using `.master("local[36]")` to specify 36 cores. Is there any other way to do that as this doesn't work in java.

```
 SparkSession spark  = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .master("local[36]")
                .config("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")
                .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "1000")
                .getOrCreate();
```

Some help will be really appreciated.

Comment: How are you running "spark-java program"? Do you have 36 cores on that machine?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Yes, I have 36 cores on that machine. My spark program is inside java main method that creates spark session instance as above and uses spark sql and core libraries other methods to create and write datasets.